# How can I make Devexpress ASPxGridView get only X rows from database instead of all rows then get X?

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, entitydatasource

Hi
I'm using EntityDataSource with Devexpress ASPXGridView and when I was watching SQL profile I realized that 'ASPxGridView' gets all rows from database then take what it needs, even if I checked 'Show pager' and put page size to X.
On the other hand Microsoft GridView control gets only 'TOP X' rows from database .. not all the rows.
My question is:
Is there a way to make 'ASPXGridView' to act like 'GridView' or it's just the way 'ASPXGridView' do it and I can't do anything with it ?

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions for you:

1)  try to set the ASPxGridView.[DataSourceForceStandardPaging](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_DataSourceForceStandardPagingtopic) property to true.  If your dataSource supports server side paging natively, the grid will work as the standard GridView.  Note, there are some limitations in this mode and all of them are listed in the help topic.

OR

2) Use the ASPxGridView in the so called server mode.  It is described in the following two topics:

[Server-side Data Management](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument3726)

[LINQ Server Mode](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument4059)